# Show multiple autocomplete options from one function with default values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a function that looks like this with some default values:

```
func showMyView(
  _ view: UIView,
  on viewController: UIViewController? = nil,
  backgroundColor: UIColor = .black,
  textColor: UIColor = .white
)
```

When someone types in `showMyView` I want it to autocomplete to show multiple options:

```
showMyView(_ view:)
showMyView(_:on)
showMyView(_:on:backgroundColor)
showMyView(_:on:backgroundColor:textColor)
```

It currently only shows:

```
showMyView(_ view:)
showMyView(_:on:backgroundColor:textColor)
```

How can I do this? Would I need to specifically define these individual methods and link them back to the main one that takes all params, or can I get swift to generate all of these automatically?

Comment: I couldn't find anything regarding this here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html and I feel the only way now is to define each signature you want seperately to get the desired outcome.